# Checking regular expression

Tags: java, android

I want to check email by using regular expression.I checked ([*-\w.]+@[*-\w.]+.[_-\w.]) for email regular expression.But "character class may not be used inside character range" error occurs.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**try** **this**

```
String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z._-a-zA-Z0-9]+";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check reqular expressions inside matches function like this

```
 if(editText.getText().toString().matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+[@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$")){
        //Valid email address
 }else{
        //Wrong email address
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static String emailExpression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,20}$";
static Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile(emailExpression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Validation

```
 if(emailValidation(editText.getText().toString()))
{
//Valid
}
else
{
// Invalid
}
```

function call validation

```
 public static boolean emailValidation(String s)
{
    if( s == null)
    {
        return false; 
    }
    else
    {
        m = emailPattern.matcher(s);
        return m.matches();
    }
}
```